# Custom CSS Not Loading with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason my HTML file is not picking up my custom CSS files for Bootstrap. Code below:

```
<head>

    <title>Site Name</title>

    <!-- METAs -->

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->

    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
```

This loads the default Bootstrap CSS, but not the styles.css file. The file is in the same directory, and there is code in it. For the life of me I can't figure this out and my only guess is it is somewhere in this head portion. I can provide other snippets if need be, and I have tried other paradigms like LESS with no luck either.

This snippet will eventually go into a PHP include file for easier editing. I have my java script saved in a similar type file at the foot of the site with the footer.

I was going to guess it was a host side issue until I tested it locally and the issue still did not resolve.

Any suggestions to help me keep my sanity would be most appreciated!

Comment: Yes.  Also, open the client-side source view and click on the link to styles.css.  If it loads, then you're looking at something like your CSS failing to override due to ! or somesuch.

Comment: How do you debug it??? Maybe your CSS file contains invalid code, and maybe at the very beginning of it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you positive that it isn't loading? What does the console say?

If it is throwing a 404, then there's something wrong with the path you're specifying. 
If it isn't throwing a 404, then it is loading and just not overriding what you want it to override.

Comment: That just about covers it :)